# hadoop in windows with cygwin noclassdefinition found error

Tags: java, windows, hadoop

i am  trying to install hadoop in  my windows 7 environment and run it with cygwin. 
i have downloaded and installed cygwin and have configured ssh
i have set java class path inside cygwin .bashrc and set up all hadoop configuration files My .bashrc file is listed

```
export JAVA_HOME="C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.6.0_24"
export HADOOP_HOME=/home/user/hadoop
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=/home/user/hadoop
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=/home/user/hadoop
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=/home/user/hadoop
export YARN_HOME=/home/user/hadoop
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/home/user/hadoop/etc/hadoop
```

but get class not found error when i run the folowing commands
the error on cygwin terminal is :

```
$ ./hadoop version
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/util/VersionInfo
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.util.VersionInfo
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
Could not find the main class: org.apache.hadoop.util.VersionInfo.  Program will exit.
Exception in thread "main"
```

why do i get a noclass definition found error, is there some thing else i need to do with configuration . am using windows 7 64bit and hadoop version 2.2.0

Comment: the hadoop version 2.2.0 is not compatible with windows.. i downgraded my hadoop to version 1.8 and it worked

Comment: Follow the steps described here http://www.srccodes.com/p/article/38/build-install-configure-run-apache-hadoop-2.2.0-microsoft-windows-os], this works perfectly to setup a Hadoop environment in a windows machine.

Answer (score 1):

Some tips:

1. Install JDK in a folder, the path must be without any white space.
2. Set the path like this:

   ```
   $ export JAVA_HOME=/cygdrive/c/Program_Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_71
   ```
3. Make sure that the export was succesfull by executing:

   ```
   $ env | grep -i JAVA_HOME
   ```

   This should print:

   ```
   JAVA_HOME=/cygdrive/c/Program_Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_71
   ```
4. If you want to see the version, just execute:

   ```
   sh -x bin/hdfs version
   ```
5. Run `.sh` scripts with `sh -x`:

   ```
   sh -x bin/hdfs namenode -format
   ```