# Able to run JUnitCore test runner from IntelliJ run config, but not form commandline

Tags: java, selenium, intellij-idea, junit, selenide

I am writing a program to automate a visitor sign up, using selenide (4.4.x) and junit (4.12). The tests run fine if I run them as a JUnit test in the IDE, but for a more convenient usage I would like to run it from main/commandline.

I managed to get this to work with an IntelliJ run configuration, but not when I attempt the same thing from the commandline. Basically, I have one abstract class that starts and stops the Selenium/ide WebDriver, a concrete test class (`RegisterVisitorTest.java`) that contains the actual reservation logic, and `RunTest.java` with a `main` method. See below for an MWE (cut irrelevant code, so it may not be executable as such).

If I create an IntelliJ run configuration with:

```
-Dselenide.browser=chrome -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="C:\downloads\chromedriver.exe" -DlastName="Peeters" -DfirstDay="5-5-2017"
```

as VM options, it then executes perfectly well and prints both "in RunTest.main", "RegisterVisitorTest", and it fills the form for me. However, if I create a jar using `mvn install` and run it as

```
java -Dselenide.browser=chrome -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="C:\downloads\chromedriver.exe" -DlastName="Peeters" -DfirstDay="5-5-2017" -cp %junit_path%;target\name-of-jar.jar x.selenide.RunTest
```

where `%junit_path% contains a reference to junit.jar and hamcrest.jar, it does go into main and prints "in RunTest.main", but it does not actually run the tests. The good news is that I don't get errors either.

However, when I run it directly as a JUnitCore runner from the commandline with:

```
java -Dselenide.browser=chrome -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="C:\downloads\chromedriver.exe" -DlastName="Peeters" -DfirstDay="5-5-2017" -cp %junit_path%;target\name-of-jar.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore nl.ing.selenide.RegisterVisitorTest
```

I get the following output:

```
JUnit version 4.12
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/support/events/WebDriverEventListener
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at org.junit.internal.Classes.getClass(Classes.java:16)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult.parseParameters(JUnitCommandLineParseResult.java:100)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult.parseArgs(JUnitCommandLineParseResult.java:50)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult.parse(JUnitCommandLineParseResult.java:44)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.runMain(JUnitCore.java:72)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.main(JUnitCore.java:36)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.support.events.WebDriverEventListener
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 8 more
```

What bothers me is that it runs fine when I run it from the IDE, but that it does not fire the test when I run main from commandline, and that it fails when I run the test directly. In my Maven project I do have a number of red lines but that does not seem to matter most of the time...

Anyway this seems to boil down to that WebDriverEventListener mentioned above, but if I attempt to add a WebDriverEventListener it can apparently find the dependency and automatically adds the correct import statement, though this does not change the outcome if I do another `mvn install`.

Am I missing something?

EDIT: Although 'class not found' is found in other SO questions, it is not a duplicate of the hadoop question mentioned, as I have the correct environment variables set.

I am able to run other JARs, just not this one.

Solved by using the Maven assembly plugin to include all dependencies.

MWE (attempt):

```
package x.selenide;
//RunTest.java
import org.junit.runner.JUnitCore;

public class RunTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("In RunTest.main");
        JUnitCore junit = new JUnitCore();
        junit.run(RegisterVisitorTest.class);
    }
}

//RegisterVisitorTest.java
public class RegisterVisitorTest extends ClickTest {

    private static String lastName;
    private static LocalDate firstDay;
    private static LocalDate lastDay;

    private static final DateTimeFormatter dateFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d-M-yyyy");

    public RegisterVisitorTest() {
        System.out.println("RegisterVisitorTest");
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUp() {
        // setup properties with System.getProperties();
    }

    @Test
    public void openRegistrationPage(){
        Selenide.$(Selectors.byText("Bezoekers aanmelden")).click();
        String parentWindowHandle = WebDriverRunner.getWebDriver().getWindowHandle();

        // switch tab/window as it opens a new window
        Set<String> handles = WebDriverRunner.getWebDriver().getWindowHandles();
        for (String handle: handles){
            if(!handle.equals(parentWindowHandle)){
                Selenide.switchTo().window(handle);
            }
        }

        // method call to fill the actual registration form
    }
}
// ClickTest.java
public abstract class ClickTest {
    @BeforeClass
    public static void openOrderSite() {
        Configuration.timeout = 10000;
        Configuration.baseUrl = "https://intranet.net";
        Configuration.startMaximized = false;
        Selenide.open("/subdomain");
        waitUntilPageIsLoaded();
    }

    private static void waitUntilPageIsLoaded() {
        waitUntilPageIsLoaded("Bezoekers aanmelden");
    }

    static void waitUntilPageIsLoaded(String expected){
        logger.info(String.format("Waiting for string '%s' to appear...", expected));
        Selenide.$(Selectors.byText(expected)).waitUntil(Condition.appears, 20000);
        logger.info("Page loaded");
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void logout() {
        WebDriverRunner.closeWebDriver();
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [hadoop in windows with cygwin noclassdefinition found error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23219089/hadoop-in-windows-with-cygwin-noclassdefinition-found-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This exception is pretty straight forward: the **classpath** is missing something. java fails to locate that `org/openqa/selenium...` class.

And all your setup mentions junit, hamcrest, ... but not selenium.

Long story short: probably your IDE adds a selenium jar to the classpath without you noticing. But when *you* run things on the command line, you need to provide *all* the elements that are needed. Selenium is missing. And probably your **own** classes as well.

Comment: Thank you! My own classes were not missing, because they are all in the target jar ;). What drove me crazy is that it started with junit missing, then hamcrest, then... where I assumed that Maven would take care of all that. I solved it using the Maven assembly plugin to create a jar with dependencies, and now I can run the main class.